# Yii Create Command can't get hard coded value from select

Tags: php, mysql, yii

This is my query

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
->select('t.id, "contract" AS type')
->from('test t')
->where('t.company_id=1')
->queryAll();
```

Am getting this error,

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '"contract"' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT `t`.`id`, `"contract"` AS `type` FROM `test` `t` WHERE t.company_id=1
```

Comment: You can try with this ->select('t.id, t.contract AS type')

Comment: Thanks for the information. Now go ahead and fix the problem!

Comment: In my table no column called contract. I need to get hard coded value.

Answer (score 0):

try using avoid literal name eg:

```
  $result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
    ->select('t.id,  case when 1 = 1 then 'contract' end AS type')
    ->from('test t')
    ->where('t.company_id=1')
    ->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with minor additional change

```
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
->select('t.id,  (case when 1 = 1 then "contract" end) AS type')
->from('test t')
->where('t.company_id=1')
->queryAll();
```